# EMF: How to map a group of XML elements with unique names to a Map

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I have an existing XML format for which I would like to create an Ecore based model that I can use to load and save files in that XML format (without writing my own serializer/deserializer). The XML contains elements with the following structure:

```
<parent>
  <some-other-element>...</some-other-element>
  ...
  <child name="name1">...</child>
  <child name="name2">...</child>
  ...
</parent>
```

The names of the `child` elements are expected to be unique among their siblings. Obviously the most natural way to model this would be to use a `Map`, `EMap` or some other map-like structure. Is it possible to use such a data structure and to annotate the model in such a way that instances of that model are persisted in the format shown above?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off going the route of creating an xsd with the unique restraints you require because using annotations I'm not sure if its possible. Maybe if you map a list to have @unique=true and than type to be the property that must be unique like type="child.name" then on the child interface/name attribute use the annotation as unique=true. that might work